# Need help in preparing waterfall chart where previous,current month PBT are taken as base , i have table of cur month but cant add prev pbt in table

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-custom-visuals

As regards the excel format attached for YTD/HTD/QTD/MTD ( for Finance Dashboard), the pending Points.
Waterfall Chart Previous Month PBT is missing. (the two PBTs are base)
The Values of increase/decrease should the variances figures. (Total Revenue, COGS, Fixed cost, Fin Cost & Depn, Other Income, One Time exception)

for this waterfall chart i took mtd variance as variance figures but how to take previous month PBT and Current Month PBT as base? How to add previous month PBT to this waterfall chart
Client gave me reference as shown in the picture below.
I have table with Total Revenue, COGS, Fixed cost, Fin Cost & Depn, Other Income, One Time exception and PBT as of current month, but dont know how to add previous month PBT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJZrh.png)

for this waterfall chart i took mtd variance as variance figures but how to take previous month PBT and Current Month PBT as base? How to add previous month PBT to this waterfall chart
Client gave me reference as shown in the picture below.
I have table with Total Revenue, COGS, Fixed cost, Fin Cost & Depn, Other Income, One Time exception and PBT as of current month, but dont know how to add previous month PBT
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJZrh.png)

Comment: What does "PBT" stand for? Do you have a measure for "PBT"? Do you have a date table? You could try `PM PBT = CALCULATE([PBT], PREVIOUSMONTH('date table'[Date]) )`

Comment: PBT means Profit Before Tax.

Comment: In the file, i created waterfall chart using sql queries, but i need to create it in power bi using dax queries, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure:

```
WaterfallAmount MTD = 
  var wfPertName = SELECTEDVALUE(WaterFall[PerticularName])
  return SWITCH(wfPertName,
    "Previous PBT", [Prev MTD](Perticulars[PerticularName] = "Profit/(Loss) before Taxes"),
    [MTD](Perticulars[PerticularName] = wfPertName)
  )
```