# Previous month and current month values should reflect when selecting in month filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard

```
MTDValu = [SumAmount] (DATESMTD(LedgerSummaryUnion[Date]))
    
MTDPerce = FORMAT(DIVIDE(MTDValu,[CurrentMTDRev]),"0.0%")
    
PreMTD = CALCULATE([MTD],(PREVIOUSMONTH(DATESMTD(LedgerSummaryUnion[Date]))))
    
Premtd= CALCULATE([SumAmount],(PREVIOUSMONTH(DATESMTD(LedgerSummaryUnion[Date]))))
    
MTD Varian = [MTD]-[Prev MTD]
    
MTD Varian % = FORMAT(DIVIDE([MTD],[CurrentMTDRev])-DIVIDE([Prev MTD],[PreviousMTDRev]),"0.0%")
    
CurrentMTDRev = CALCULATE(LedgerSummaryUnion[SumMonthRev],DATESMTD(LedgerSummaryUnion[Date]))
    
SumMonthRev = ABS(CALCULATE(SUM(LedgerSummaryUnion[MonthRevenue])/100000))
```

these are some measures i wrote for calculating current month and previous month values, but while selecting current month previous month value should also reflect, need help in this.
Do i need to change my dax or anything else?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi0Z9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH1FD.png)
in the above attached file, if i click may i get current mtd details but previous mtd details are not reflecting.
I need previous mtd details also, please help. I need to show the requirement to client by evening.

This is the link for the pbix file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s29VV.png)- ledgersummaryunionn table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6AbN.png)- Image after using debug measures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to mention that your Month slicer is from another table.

Update your measure to:

```
PreMTD = 
  CALCULATE(
    [MTD],
    REMOVEFILTERS(PBI_Dates),
    PREVIOUSMONTH(LedgerSummaryUnion[Date])
  )
```

Comment: No, its not a proper date table, the values are not reflecting while using the date table , so i used ledger summary union's date column where i'm taking every value from ledger summary union. and while using the above answer, i got previous value,but when selecting the month in month filter its not showing previous month value

Comment: Did you try the debug measures above? Did you get anything for the `MTD PrevM x` measures?

Comment: Yes, i got current MTD, but while calculating the prev mtd, Cuurent mtd value is reflecting. Can you please help me how to get previous mtd value.
I tried all the four measures, debug MTD value came exactly while using the dates table date and ledgersummaryunion date which is not the date table too. 
Tried the other three measures to calculate previous month values but it is still showing the current month values in previous month column.
I'm happy to share that single month selection is working now and if the values reflect correctly it will be done. Thank you.

Comment: Please share a screen grab of all the debug measures in a Table visual with a Month selected in the slicer. I want to know what each debug measure returns. Or share the PBIX and we'll have it fixed in minutes.

Comment: [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77644346/edit) above to include the screengrab, and also please add a screengrab of your `LedgerSummaryUnion` table with all columns visible and ideally, a few rows with different months.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question and shared my pbix file both with debug mtd changes and without changes and added other screenshots.

Comment: Please upload your PBIX to public share (like OneDrive, GoogleDrive, DropBox etc...) and share a link to that.

Comment: Original File
"C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\Exell PBI Report Final.pbix"
Debug measures used file
"C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\Exell PBI Report Final mtd-premtd.pbix"

Comment: You need to share a public link to your file. In Explorer, right click on your file then OneDrive > Share. Then copy that link. And best to change it from Can Edit to **Can View**

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiqSfpZGR5JlkVVZnsFl1VZLBtmU?e=PFCi7W

to View only

Comment: Updated answer above. Strongly suggest you remove the previous Edit share link, or remove the files from OneDrive.

Comment: Can you please help in creating waterfall chart in the same data, with previous month profit before tax and current month all values

Comment: see answer posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77612627